# excluding an internal element while slicing

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

So I've got a list...

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I can produce b without 5 by saying:

```
b = a[:-1]
```

How do I produce c without 3?

```
c = a[:2:]?
```

Comment: actually, the "duplicate" doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to slice twice and concatenate the lists , Example -

```
c = a[:2] + a[3:]  #2 being the index of element `3` in the array.
```

Demo -

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[:2] + a[3:]
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding two lists

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> c = a[:3-1] + a[3:]   # Explicitly mentioned 3-1 to help understand better
>>> c
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

An inplace way to remove

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a.pop(3-1)
3
>>> a
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to join the two list parts together as follows

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
c = a[:2] + a[3:]
c
[1,2,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just pop the index out i.e.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a.pop(2)
>>> 3
>>> print(a)
[1,2,4,5]
```